# Web view displaying small crashed image icon after I click yes icon on camera intent screen

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview, android-camera

I am creating an app to load an URL in web view. I have created Image chooser to start activity for choose the photo from gallery and camera.

A) Select image from gallery is working perfectly. 
B) When I capture image through camera then It is showing crashed small image icon in web view.

**Note :** Camera photo is displaying perfectly on web view when I stay more then 5-8 seconds on Camera screen after image captured. But It should be work even I press YES button quickly after captured the image.

**Here is my web view Code for set WebChromeClient**

```
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> newFilePathCallback,
                    FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

                if (filePathCallback != null) {
                    filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                filePathCallback = newFilePathCallback;

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    Log.d("Mainn", "onShowFileChooser()");
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d("Mainn", "onShowFileChooser().. e : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Log.d("Mainn", "onShowFileChooser() 4");
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        Log.d("Mainn", "onShowFileChooser() 5");
                        cameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        Log.d("Mainn", "onShowFileChooser() 6");
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }
                Log.d("Mainn", "onShowFileChooser() 7");
                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    Log.d("Mainn", "onShowFileChooser() 8");
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    Log.d("Mainn", "onShowFileChooser() 9");
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Log.d("Mainn", "onShowFileChooser() 10");
                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

**onActivityResult() Code is here**

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || filePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

        Uri[] results = null;

        // Check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (cameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(cameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }
            }
        }

        filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        filePathCallback = null;

    }
```

Comment: Uri.fromFile() will not help you. Use FileProvider instead.

Comment: `Camera photo is displaying perfectly on web view when I stay more then 5-8 seconds`??? But then the subject and the context of your post is wrong.

Comment: @blackapps I have edited my post. Please Let me know If you have not understood about my problem. I searched lots of things on internet but nothing found for it. Please give me a way to overcome this.

Comment: @blackapps Can you please provide FlileProvider code ?

Comment: Google is your friend. Or just read some pages here. They are talking about FileProvider now.

Comment: Your formulation of the problem still is strange. As your problem is that the captured picture is only displaying after a few seconds.

Comment: Wow! It is working perfectly after I used a FileProvider. Thank you @blackapps for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use FileProvider instead of Uri.fromFile(). It will solve this problem.

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), getActivity().getPackageName(), photoFile);
takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
```